# What is the fastest way to merge tens of millions of files

Tags: bash, shell, go

There are 50 million files, stored on an ubuntu computer, I want to merge these 50 million into several large files, how to do it the fastest?
At present, I have saved the filename to be processed in `filename.txt` through the `ls -1` command

I tried writing a go program that reads a file, and in turn reads the output to a file, but I found it too slow. The actual reading speed is about 1s to merge 30-40 files, and it takes more than 16 days to finish it.

Is there any good way to merge quickly?

Here is the go code I wrote:

```golang
const fileSizeLimit = (1 << 30) * 4 // 4GB
const filesStorePath = "<>"
func main() {
    fileNamesFile := ""
    outBasePath := ""

    startId := 0

    //del := false
    flag.StringVar(&fileNamesFile, "d", "", "filenames file")
    flag.StringVar(&outBasePath, "o", "", "out dir")
    flag.IntVar(&startId, "f", 0, "start fn")
    //flag.BoolVar(&del, "del", false, "del file")

    flag.Parse()

    start := time.Now()

    fmt.Printf("start：%s\n", start.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
    fmt.Printf("file names = %s\n", fileNamesFile)
    fmt.Printf("out dir = %s\n", outBasePath)


    allList, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(fileNamesFile)
    all := strings.Split(string(allList), "\n")
    total := len(all)
    store := newStoreItems(outBasePath, startId)

    uiLiveWriter := uilive.New()
    uiLiveWriter.Start()

    finish := make(chan bool, 1)
    pos := 0
    readCount := 0

    go func() {
        for i := pos; i < total; i++ {
            pos = i
            fn := all[i]

            f := path.Join(filesStorePath, fn)
            if content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(f); err == nil {
                store.write(content)
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
        // 当前文件
        for true {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                t := time.Since(start)
                cost := t.Seconds()
                content := fmt.Sprintf("read %d/%d(%.2f%%), file=%d/%d, speed=%d/s\ttime %s\n",
                    pos, total, float64(pos)/float64(total)*100,
                    store.index, store.getSize(),
                    int(float64(readCount) / cost),
                    (time.Duration(cost) * time.Second).String())

                _, _ = fmt.Fprint(uiLiveWriter, content)
            }
        }
    }()

    osSignals := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(osSignals, os.Interrupt, os.Kill, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGKILL)
    go func() {
        s := <-osSignals
        fmt.Println("stop !", s)

        finish <- false
    }()

    <-finish
    close(finish)

    _, _ = fmt.Fprintln(uiLiveWriter, "Finished ")
    uiLiveWriter.Stop() // flush and stop rendering
    fmt.Println("readCount", readCount)
    fmt.Println("exit 0")


}


type storeItems struct {
    basePath string
    w        *bufio.Writer
    file     *os.File
    size     int
    rowSize  int64
    index    int
    lock     sync.Mutex
}

func newStoreItems(storePath string, startFn int) *storeItems {
    fn := path.Join(storePath, strconv.Itoa(startFn))
    f, err := os.OpenFile(fn, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("create [%s] fail! err: %s \n", fn, err)
    }

    return &storeItems{
        basePath: storePath,
        w:  bufio.NewWriterSize(f, util.GIGABYTE),
        file: f,
        size:  0,
        index: startFn,
    }
}

func (s *storeItems) getSize() int {
    return s.size
}

func (s *storeItems) nextFile() *os.File {
    if s.file != nil {
        _ = s.w.Flush()
        _ = s.file.Close()
    }
    nextIndex := s.index+1

    s.file, _ = os.OpenFile(path.Join(s.basePath, strconv.Itoa(nextIndex)),
        os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0600)
    s.w = bufio.NewWriterSize(s.file, util.GIGABYTE)
    s.index = nextIndex
    s.size = 0
    return s.file
}

func (s *storeItems) write(b []byte) {
    _, _ = s.w.Write(b)
    _, _ = s.w.WriteRune('\n')
    s.size += len(b) + 1

    if s.w.Size() >= fileSizeLimit {
        // cut off file
        s.nextFile()
    }
}
```

execute output:

```
start：2022-07-22 05:03:09
file names = ***
out dir = ***
read 9057/50803783(0.02%), file=0/48151629, speed=40/s  time 3m41s
```

Observed system reads and writes: read: 4 M/s ~ 9 M/s

I have also tried using `awk` and `cat` commands, but the effect is about the same as go.

```bash
head ~/filename.txt -n 10000 | xargs awk '1' >> ~/out/0
sed -i '1,10000d' ~/filename.txt
```

Comment: If it's really about performance, my feeling is that a pure C solution would be better than one in Go. Also, first splitting the file on newlines to create an array could be a performance bottleneck, unless the file is small.

Comment: Yes, the files are very small, average 4K-8K each,
Sorry I don't know C language

Comment: I don't know about the performance of the various operators in Go, , but in this case I would first do a benchmark of various parts of your code to see where most time is spent. Your question boils down to how to do file processing efficiently in Go, so I would drop the _bash_ and _shell_ tag, as it seems then to be a pure Go question.

Comment: @jjjjyx : "merge" as in joining by columns+criteria, or straight up file concat, or in the horizontal sense like `paste` ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto what I call merging, which is combining tens of millions of small files into a large one, a readable file.

Comment: @user1934428 that I don't want to use GO to solve this problem, I prefer to use bash

Comment: @user1934428 : go is a tool to achieve my purpose, I am looking for a way to make file merging faster to shorten the time, if possible, I would like to use bash commands to solve it, because I think it is efficient, but I am not skilled, only Can do and write the above kind of command.

Comment: @jjjjyx : then why not just `find …. -print0 | xargs -0 cat `

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Without a newline at the end of the file, using the `cat` command will make the merged file a single line. Add a newline by using `awk 1`

Comment: @jjjjyx : xargs -0 -n 1 cat then

Comment: Just for the record: The language is not as important as it may sounds, I'd rather expect the IO to be the bottleneck. If you can, store the output on a separate storage than the input. Also, do nonblocking IO then, so you don't go back'n'forth between blocking on either IO channel. Goroutines and channels make this really convenient to write in Go.

Comment: I'd imagine you're being hit by disk I/O seek times, jumping around to find 50 million files. A 512GB NVME SSD is around $80 and would probably make a world of difference if you do this often. Just a thought.

Comment: @MarkSetchell As you said, that's exactly what I did to prepare for the migration to a faster NVME  SSD  disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use separate tools here: `cat` for joining the existing content, and `split` for creating chunks that have the desired output size. E.g.:

```
cat filename.txt | xargs cat | split -b 1M
```

With a million test files this runs at about 100K files/s on my PC, so it would complete for 50M files within 10 minutes. I did run this on tmpfs though and with only 4 bytes/file, though.

So, those numbers reflect the best case scenarion. If disk (or filesystem) speed is the bottleneck in your case then there's little that you can do about it I think. Still, I wouldn't expect that your setup would increase the runtime from ten minutes to two weeks : )

Comment: I too would have answered along a pure bash solution. But with 50M files, I would take care of maximum command line width, and if performance is still an issue I would juggle with several SSD and parallelize the operations.

Comment: Well, it seems that the speed limit of the hdd drive can not be solved from the software level, so I give up optimizing the speed

Comment: I've learned another `split` command, thanks!